# HTML/JS - Google Maps v3 - select/remove marker by id from external link

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm new to google maps and javascript . I'm trying to interact with the map using external links/lists.

My main problem is that i'm unable to select the marker on the map with its id.

I don't want to put all markers in a list/array and iterate over them since i don't know how many there will be at any point.

I simply want to select them by their id and work with them such as opening infowindow , removing them etc...

in my changeIcon() function , i tried some ways but none worked so far .

```
<html>

....

<div id="mapview"></div>

<a class="test-link" onmouseover="changeIcon()">Link</a>

<script>

function changeIcon()
    {
        //marker = map.selectMarker("4");
        //marker = markers[4];
        //infowindow.open(map,marker);

        //$("#mapview").map.removeMarker(4);
    }

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapview'), 
        {
            center: {lat: 44.540, lng: -78.546},
            zoom: 16
        });

function initMap() 
{
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: userPosition,
          map: map,
          id: 4
        });
}

</script>

</html>
```

............................................

Answer (score -1):

There is no API to get marker from map. ref: 
"https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference"

I think you dont want to use array because id will never match the index. So I suggest using dictionary:

```
var markers = {};  // "{}" to specify dictionary instead of "[]" to specify array
```

when you create marker, you add it to dictionary:

```
markers[4] = marker;   // 4 is the id
```

when you want to get it:

```
var currentMarker = markers[4];
```